# Split page into many numbered Divs and reload whole page when clicking to show the hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My code:

```
<div class="content_1">    
//Content of first page goes
</div>
<div class="content_2" style="display:none;">
//Content of second page goes here
</div>
<div class="content_3" style="display:none;">
//Third page content goes here
</div>

<p>Pages: 
<a href="#" class="button_1"> 1</a>
<a href="#" class="button_2"> 2</a>
<a href="#" class="button_3"> 3</a></p>
<div class="clearLeft"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var a = 200;
$('.button_1').css("background-color","#00CCFF");
$('.button_1').click(function(){
    $('.content_1').fadeIn(a);
    $('.content_2').fadeOut();
    $('.content_3').fadeOut();
        $('.content_4').fadeOut();
    $('.button_1').css("background-color","#00CCFF");
    $('.button_2').css("background-color","#99FF99");
        $('.button_3').css("background-color","#99FF99");
        $('.button_4').css("background-color","#99FF99");
});
$('.button_2').click(function(){
    $('.content_1').fadeOut();
    $('.content_2').fadeIn(a);
    $('.content_3').fadeOut();
        $('.content_4').fadeOut();
    $('.button_2').css("background-color","#00CCFF");
    $('.button_1').css("background-color","#99FF99");
        $('.button_3').css("background-color","#99FF99");
        $('.button_4').css("background-color","#99FF99");
});
$('.button_3').click(function(){
    $('.content_1').fadeOut();
    $('.content_2').fadeOut();
    $('.content_3').fadeIn(a);
        $('.content_4').fadeOut();
        $('.button_3').css("background-color","#00CCFF");
        $('.button_1').css("background-color","#99FF99");
        $('.button_2').css("background-color","#99FF99");
        $('.button_4').css("background-color","#99FF99");
});
});
</script>
```

I want to refresh the page on clicking the buttons and show the hidden div. I tried many things but the result was page reload and show the first div again whatever button chosen.

Edit: Code above is working well with Jquery library. I want to add extra property to the code. I want page reloads when clicking buttons and keep the div shown.

Example: When click on button "2" I want page to be reloaded and show "//Content of second page goes here"

Comment: you have to store some value somewhere (may be a cookie, a querystring.. something) to show the hidden div.

Comment: What do you mean with page refresh? If you refresh page you need to get some params from url and show specified div by using that url param. Please explain more, because your code is working as you said http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/Vmtbt/

Comment: you did not reference jQuery library i guess ;)

Comment: thanks for giving a hand. Please see the edited part of the question for more illustration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try jSCookie

I did,

```
  var clickedLink = getCookie('getClickedLink');
  if(clickedLink){
  $("button:eq(" + (parseInt(clickedLink) -1) + ")").addClass('tiklandi');
  }

  $("button").on('click', function(){
      $(this).addClass('tiklandi');
      var tikTik = $(this).attr('rel');
      setCookie("getClickedLink", tikTik);
  });
```

**Check it** http://jsfiddle.net/2dn9q/1/

Comment: `live` has been deprecated for quite a long time now and also doesn't exist in current version of jQUery  http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: thank you for atttention. I replaced on()

Comment: I added the above code but page don't reload. thanks for giving a hand. Please see the edited part of the question for more illustration

Answer (score 0):

Its working just use this line in top of your page

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```